# How do I structure my database calls for easy testing?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I've tasted the T(B)DD Kool-Aid, and I'm firmly convinced of its merit, especially in giving me confidence that my code is correct*

I've been pondering lately about the best way to structure my code to make unit testing possible. I've read a few different articles (like [this one](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/08/19/how-to-unit-test-code-that-interacts-with-a-database/)), and of course they say stay away from production databases (we already do that here). I think I'm pretty comfortable with the concepts, but I'm having issues figuring out what the best code layout is. Currently most of the functions that interact with the database look like this:

```
Function GetSomething(ByVal someData as DataType) as ResultType
    Connect to database
    create command/transaction
    initialise result variables
    Try
        lines and lines of SQL
        add parameters
        perform query
        While reader.read()
           read data into result variables
        End While
    Catch ex as DB2Exception 'Since we use db2, of course
        Do stuff
    Finally
        Clean up database variables
    End Try
    return results
End Function
```

And almost every query is written the same way, company-wide. Obviously this doesn't lend itself to testability because I would have to break into the function to actually test it. So I was thinking - why not pull the actual access functions out, and then I can test that they work appropriately. I was thinking that maybe I should have a function that simply performs the query and returns the reader (or some type of table with the results in it). Then I would be able to directly test the data access function and that would give me the ability to, say roll back transactions.

Are there any articles or questions with examples of what the "correct" method is for testing this layer?

We use VB and C# here, but I think the concept is fairly language agnostic, and I have no problem reading the more common programming languages.

*At least as correct as my tests ;)

### Edit:

To clarify, I'm looking for **how to structure my code** for testing, e.g. I **do not** want code that looks like this:

```
Property Testing as Boolean
Public Sub SomeInsertOrUpdateStatement(ByVal param as DataType)
    OpenConnection()
    Try
        If Testing Then
            ' Do one thing
        Else
            ' Do another thing
        End If
     Finally
        CloseConnection()
     End Try
End Sub
```

But I'm not entirely sure what the Best Code should look like.

Comment: You should definitly **avoid** littering your production code with these `Testing` booleans. You should be able to ship your production code without **any** reference to your testcases. Your testcases should be contained within a seperate project referencing your production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say Integration tests if this is the boundary between your app and the DB.

There should be a Role/Interface (CustomerRepository) and an implementation(SqlCustomerRepository).

- Unit tests : to test the rest of the app uses a fake/mock based on the CustomerRepository interface. The role abstracts the app from the technology used to implement the repository
- Integration tests : However the code that you posted above looks like it belongs in the SqlCustomerRepository. The only way to test it is to invoke the interface methods and see if it works with a real Sql DB. No mocking or faking here... these tests will be slow (you can tag it with a category to run them less frequently) but they verify if the SqlCustomerRepository satisfies the CustomerRepository contract.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in my question (which is what I get for posting right before heading home!) - I'm fairly comfortable with the when/where/why/how of *testing*, it's structuring my DB call code for testing that I'm struggling with. I updated my question to (hopefully) be a little more clear.

Comment: @WayneWerner - my answer was since the class you're writing looks like the class responsible for getting stuff out of a DB, you should be writing integration tests - your code doesn't need to change. You just to need run some tests with a reference DB. You definitely don't want IF_TESTING kind of flags in code. Also this layer can't mock the DB layer, because then there would be nothing left to test.